# What to do about Bounty questions without 'correct' answer?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I've asked the question [How does the log reader process bulk updates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/how-does-the-log-reader-process-bulk-updates) which hasn't received a correct answer...  (useful pointers from @mrdenny, but not an answer to the actual question)...

As the asker and bounty supplier, what should the etiquette be for when the bounty period ends?

As a side note, this is part of the chicken and egg problem whereby because there aren't enough users of Database Administrators, I'm not finding the users who actually knows the answer to my particular question.  This reduces the relevance of this site to me and reduces the chance that I will come here **first** to get the answer to any hard DBA questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not receive an answer you are happy with, do not award the bounty. Better answers may be forthcoming.

If you do not award the bounty within the 7 day bounty period, the bounty may be awarded through the community vote. Any answers posted after the bounty started with at least 2 up-votes are eligible for auto-accept and will earn half the bounty amount. If there aren’t any answers meeting that criteria, no bounty is awarded.

Adding a bounty does not *guarantee* that you will receive an answer. It is up to the community to highlight particularly intriguing questions and do their best to *get* those questions answered. That answer-rate percentage is really important to the future of this site.

Use those social bookmarks!

[image: Social Bookmarks]

Comment: good points from both yourself and @jcolebrand, didn't realise that the half bounty only occurs when an answer has at least 2 up votes...

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you have hit the mark. This site is still in its infancy, and all that can be done is for each of us to evangelize relentlessly. What that means for you, is that today, with this question, you're stuck between a rock and a hardplace.

However, don't get too discouraged, the intent of this site was always to find the hard questions, and to get them in front of people so we can get more of the dba's like you're wanting to have here. This is an opportunity to ask for help, so if you think it's worth the trouble, you could always hit twitter's #sqlhelp to see if someone can contribute to the Q. There is a twitter link to the left of the questionbody. But since I've already done that once, and don't wanna be seen as spamming that feed, I'm gonna ask that each of us posit our own Qs to that hashtag when we have a need. Maybe eventually some of those guys will start coming here on a regular basis. I know we already have two users from that braintrust on here, and I know that guys like mrdenny are really strong in the community.

As for the bounty itself, when it expires this evening, it will be gone if you don't have someone to award it to. Your options are to award it to mrdenny or to let it fall away. FWIW I don't mind upping the bounty to a larger one after this one expires, if that would help you feel better. (out of my own pocket, as it were)

Comment: thank you, don't worry about upping the bounty, hopefully it will eventually be answered.  We'll most likely do some of our own tests on that question eventually (in which case I'll add the answer when we know it!)  :-)